# Modifying layer palette in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interface, qgis-customization

I am creating a simplified user interface in QGIS 3.10 for casual users in our company.

It's fairly easy to customize the menus, toolbars and activate/deactivate palettes.

But when it comes to **modifying the content** of the palettes I am stuck.
I would really like to know, how to modify the buttons and the context menu in the layers palette.

Does anyone know how to do this?